# Sitecore multisite with MVC not working

Tags: sitecore, sitecore-mvc

System.InvalidOperationException: Multiple types were found that match the controller named 'Home'. This can happen if the route that services this request ('{*pathInfo}') does not specify namespaces to search for a controller that matches the request. If this is the case, register this route by calling an overload of the 'MapRoute' method that takes a 'namespaces' parameter.

The request for 'Home' has found the following matching controllers:
SitecoreMVC.Areas.Site1.Controllers.HomeController
SitecoreMVC.Areas.Site2.Controllers.HomeController

Above is the error which I get using MVCAreas as well, I've extended the Controller Rendering template and added two more fields which are Area and Namespace and during initialize route i'm doing the AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

I've also extended the GetRendererProcessor with my custom processor and i get error at controllerrunner in execute method as complier is not able to resolve the correct controller, in the below code namespace and area is passed but still it throws error.

> AreaControllerRenderer.cs

```
 public class AreaControllerRenderer : Renderer
{
    public string Action { get; set; }
    public string Controller { get; set; }
    public string Area { get; set; }
    public string Namespaces { get; set; }

    public override string CacheKey
    {
        get
        {
            return "areacontroller::" + Controller + "#" + Action + "#" + Area + "#" + Namespaces;
        }
    }

    public override void Render(System.IO.TextWriter writer)
    {
        var controllerRunner = new AreaControllerRunner(Controller, Action, Area, Namespaces);

        string value = controllerRunner.Execute();
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
        {
            return;
        }
        writer.Write(value);
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "Controller: {0}. Action: {1}. Area {2}. Namespaces {3}".FormatWith(new object[]
        {
            Controller,
            Action,
            Area,
            Namespaces
        });
    }
}
```

Please help!!

I was able to Solve this issue using the Fully Qualified Name of the controller with Assembly name as below -
`SitecoreMVC.Areas.Site1.Controllers.HomeController, SitecoreMVC`

Comment: what version of Sitecore are you using?

Comment: @sitecore climber - I'm using Sitecore 8.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Sitecore `ControllerFactory` currently doesn't allow to have multiple controllers with the same name. You have to choose a different name for each controller or add the fullname of your controller (including the assembly) into your controller rendering:

```
SitecoreMVC.Areas.Site1.Controllers.HomeController, SitecoreMVC
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply so If I understood correctly I need to put  SitecoreMVC.Areas.Site1.Controllers.HomeController  in the Controller Rendering right?

Comment: I tried using the Fully Qualified name of the controller in the controller rendering but now it gives error as -
[ExceptionWrapper: The controller for path '/' was not found or does not implement IController.]

[ControllerCreationException: Could not create controller: 'SitecoreMVC.Areas.Site1.Controller.Home'. 
The context item is: '/sitecore/content/Site1'.

Comment: @ParitoshTripathi try adding the assembly name as well: "SitecoreMVC.Areas.Site1.Controllers.HomeController, AssemblyName"

Comment: I tried using the Assembly name as well but still the same error -
[InvalidOperationException: Could not create a controller instance from type name: 'SitecoreMVC.Areas.Site1.Controller.HomeController, SitecoreMVC']
   Sitecore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerRunner.CreateControllerUsingReflection() +326
   Sitecore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerRunner.GetController() +24
   Sitecore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerRunner.Execute() +54
   Framework.Sc.Extensions.MvcAreas.AreaControllerRenderer.Render(TextWriter writer) in d:\Projects\SitecoreMVC_Soln\Sitecore.Extensions\MvcAreas\AreaControllerRenderer.cs:32

Comment: Am I missing something? Plz help.

Comment: @ParitoshTripathi this is now a different error message ;-) In the error message I see in your namespace ".Controller." instead of ".Controllers." (see the missing "s"). Are you sure that you have entered the correct namespace and classname to the controller rendering?

Comment: Hey Thanks Kevin, Silly Typo was the cause. It worked but now there is another piece to it that is the site getting loaded is Site1 no matter i change the url from dev.site1.com or dev.site2.com.

Comment: I've edited the question with current problem now. Please take a look and tell me if I missed anything in this as well. I hope not...

Comment: @ParitoshTripathi I think this is another problem and not related to this question. Could you please mark the answer as accepted and open a new question?

Answer (score 1):

You can restrict the namespaces to search in per sitecore-site when using the solution I blogged about:
http://www.chrisvandesteeg.nl/2014/06/13/sitecore-mvc-in-a-multisite-environment-areas/

What does your ToString() return when the Render method is called?

Comment: I tried your blog as well but scRoute variable is always null as the MvcSettings.SitecoreRouteName variable is set from the Sitecore.MVC.Config and default value is  
<setting name="Mvc.SitecoreRouteName" value="Sitecore" />

And the render method ToString() returns -
"Controller: SitecoreMVC.Areas.Site1.Controller.HomeController, SitecoreMVC. Action: Index. Area Site1. Namespaces SitecoreMVC.Areas.Site1.Controller"

Comment: Is the custom initialroutes at the end of the initialize pipeline? Try the 'fantastic' zzzz way like zzzz.initializeroutes.config to be sure it gets included last.

Answer (score 0):

In Sitecore 8.1 MVC areas are out of the box supported, maybe you can use Sitecore 8.1 instead of 8.0 http://ctor.io/new-in-sitecore-8-1-mvc-areas/

Comment: Actually i know it works in Sitecore 8.1 but I wanted to try it in earlier versions. Thanks for your suggestion.